How to solve cp: cannot stat 00000002.history: No such file or directory/LOG: invalid primary checkpoint record during PITR?
I have tried to recover a database, using the Point-in-Time Recovery method, through the postgresql.conf file, setting the recovery_target_time parameter at a specific time in past, but I cannot start the cluster and recover the database, I am getting the following output in the log file:
2024-08-08 09:37:11.429 CEST [3492124] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2024-07-13 21:12:24 CEST
cp: cannot stat '/appl/pgsql/15/bkp/WAL/00000002.history': No such file or directory
2024-08-08 09:37:11.443 CEST [3492124] LOG:  starting point-in-time recovery to 2024-07-14 20:00:00+02
2024-08-08 09:37:11.443 CEST [3492124] LOG:  invalid primary checkpoint record
2024-08-08 09:37:11.443 CEST [3492124] PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record
2024-08-08 09:37:11.556 CEST [3492120] LOG:  startup process (PID 3492124) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
2024-08-08 09:37:11.556 CEST [3492120] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
2024-08-08 09:37:11.558 CEST [3492120] LOG:  database system is shut down

I have seen different questions similar to mine, but also different answers, so I am not sure what can be the problem.
What I can imagine is that it must have something to do with the version of the database, which is the 15, I have seen some things related to backup have changed since this version has been released, but I am not sure. Has anyone had this issue before?

Your backup seems to be corrupt, presumably because you took the backup using some incorrect method.  If you try to do a regular recovery (not PITR) you will probably get the same error about 'invalid primary checkpoint record'.  The history file error is likely not the problem, as recovery is expected to ask for some files which don't exist, that is normal.

I'd say you are missing some WAL segments.

I have a WAL segment from Jul 13 21:12 and another from Jul 14 21:12. I am trying to recover the database to 2024-07-14 20:00:00+02. Shouldn't it work? Isn't this time saved in between my two WAL segments?

You need all the WAL segments from when the backup was initiated through to the PITR end point.  The problem is with the very first needed WAL segment, not one in the middle.
